# Linux-app does not get UDP messages from 169.254.x.x (local link)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, udp, broadcast

My application (written in C++, running on Ubuntu 9.10) is listening on a UDP socket for broadcast messages from external devices.
Those devices can have any IP address, since the idea is to communicate beyond IP ranges.

When the devices have IP addresses such as 99.99.1.2, 1.2.3.4, 0.0.0.1, 192.168.2.77 etc, it works fine (the PC itself is 192.168.1.110).
But: it does not work when the device has **169.254.x.x** (the local link block), the application doesn't get the message. There is no firewall running, and Wireshark **does** show the message, so the connection is OK. I assume the problem somewhere in the IP stack (I open device /dev/eth2 and get the socket, so nothing special).

Any idea for a reason or a solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that I found the reason. Anyway, thanks to those who suggested solutions.

I didn't mention that my Ubuntu is running in a VM (which is basically not the problem since Wireshark got the messages)

The interfaces are:
**eth2** is the interface I was talking about above (thus, which does the external communication via broadcasts). It is a "**bridged**" one.

Additionally, I had implemented an internal "**host-only**" network interface **eth4** to communicate with other VMs.

I had also added a "**default**" route for eth2, otherwise the broadcast communication wouldn't have worked at all.

However, what I did not notice was the automatically inserted "**link-local**" route which pointed to **eth4**. So I conclude that the system uses this one to handle all 169.254.x.x messages and my application doesn't get them any more.

Two ways solved my problem:

- Disabling eth4 at all or
- removing the "link-local" route with

  route del -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth4

Here's the routing table before removing the route:

```
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.230.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth4
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth2
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth4
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     10     0        0 eth2
```

Now I can happily receive all packets from the devices I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that eth2 has an IP address and netmask and that that IP address and netmask puts it on the same IP network as the device. Use the command `ifconfig` to see these details.

Comment: The idea is that the application receives messages from all IP addresses **at the same time** no matter what they are. The app is kind of a service tool, and it must be able to handle different devices. Cannot use ifconfig here.

Comment: Well, it seems like you have two choices; (a) do what I said, but without ifconfig; or (b) see what wireshark is doing, and replicate its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that rp_filter is turned off on all interfaces that you want to receive broadcast UDP when your ip is 169.254.x.x

```
# sysctl -A | grep '\.rp_filter'
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 0
```

To set the rp_filter use

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to double check if you have a firewall blocking them.
On linux you're probably using [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables). Use that command to list
your rules. Many distros implement firewalls using iptables but hide
that fact from you.

Routers aren't supposed to forward packets from 192.*.*.* because that's not a "routable" subnet. It's supposed to only be used for internal/local use.
If there's a router or bridge between the source and destination that may be the problem.
If you have wireshark on the same machine that's listening for the packets and you can
see them then this is NOT the issue.

You might use [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) to ensure your program is actually listening.
Type 'netstat -an -p UDP" to see all the programs that are listening for udp packets.

---

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks, I will check for iptables soon (after Easter...) but I'm pretty sure that there is none (it is a test machine in the lab without internet connection).
Yes, Wireshark is on this machine, so the packet does reach the system.
And the app can receive packets from serveral devices at the same time: I had two devices, and it received both packages when they were different to 169.xxx and it received only one when the other device **was** 169. So the app **is** actually listening.

Comment: "Routers aren't supposed to forward packets from 192...*" is wrong. The RFC 1918 reserved subnet is 192.168/16, not 192/8. Subnets of 192.168/16 are absolutely routable, and it's done quite often. They just can't be routed *to the Internet* because many different sites are using the same addresses.

Comment: @Andrew: How is a router supposed to know when it's connected to the internet and not just used internally?